# Trouble with graph generation function in Node-RED dashboard

Tags: charts, node-red, textinput

I am currently developing a Node-RED dashboard where I aim to generate a chart based on user inputs. The chart generation process involves selecting a specific year through a button and providing the name of one or two products using text input fields.

Here is the current state of my implementation:
[Node-red flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA0nx.png)
Each button in the dashboard is associated with a specific topic, and the node switch is performed based on the topic selected by the user. The text inputs have a similar configuration, and the function responsible for handling the inputs is as follows:

```
context.global.input_data= msg.payload
msg.payload = context.global.input_data
return msg;
```

I'm encountering issues with the graph generation function:

```
var input_data = context.global.input_data (text inputs)
var year2017 = []
var year2017_global = []
var data= []

for(var inp in inpuy_data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.payload.length; i++) {
        if(msg.payload[i].Product == data[inp]) {
            if(msg.payload[i]["Energy"]) {
                 year2017.push({"x": msg.payload[i].Year, "y": msg.payload[i]["Energy"]})
            }
        }
    }
    year2017_global.push(year2017)
    data.push(input_data[int])
}

x = [{
    "series": ??,
    "data": year2017_global ,
    "labels": ??
}]
msg.payload = x
return msg;
```

The chart is not appearing. What should I include in the series and labels? Is there something wrong with the function? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- "series": This field represents the different data groups or series that will be displayed on the chart. You can populate the "series" field by pushing each item from the input_data array into the data array. For example:
  *"series": ["Series A", "Series B", "Series C"]* -> you are pushing each input_data item into the data array
- "data": Contains the actual data points to be plotted on the chart. You can use the year2017_global array to fill the "data" field.
- "labels": Refers to the labels or names for the different categories or data points on the chart. Provide appropriate labels based on your specific data and categories.

Additionally, it is important to reset the value of year2017 to an empty array after completing the first for loop (after `data.push(input_data[int])`), or alternatively, you can declare `var year2017 = []` inside the outer for loop (`for (var inp in input_data) {`).

I hope it works now.